# Maven2 add appassembler:assemble to package goal

Tags: maven, maven-2

Is it possible to add the `appassembler: assemble` goal to the "package" goal?

I really just want assemble to run when I do a "mvn package"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cant you just add a execution tag to the appassembler plugin definition?

```
  <plugin>
      ....
   <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>package</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>assemble</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: you have them flipped around, should be <id>package</id>...<goal>assemble</goal>